# Showing ListFragment within Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment

I'm trying to display a ListFragment that'll show user comments from within another Fragment. For testing purposes, I'm calling the ListFragment using an "onClick" method from within the parent Fragment. However, I can't seem to get the ListFragment to show, as it has no "show" method. Are there any obvious problems with my code that I can fix?

This is the method called when I click a button to show the ListFragment.

```
private void showComments(JSONArray comments) {
    ListFragment newFragment = CommentsFragment.newInstance(comments);
}
```

And here is the ListFragment itself.

```
public class CommentsFragment extends ListFragment {

public static CommentsFragment newInstance(JSONArray passedComments) {
    CommentsFragment f = new CommentsFragment();
    ArrayList<String> adapter = convertJSON(passedComments);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArrayList("adapter", adapter);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    ArrayList<String> commentsArray = args.getStringArrayList("adapter");
    ArrayAdapter<String> commentsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(  
             getActivity(), R.layout.comments_list,  
             commentsArray);  
    setListAdapter(commentsAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit the ListFragment with a FragmentManager, and also have a layout in the XML that will contain it.

Firstly add a FrameLayout to the XML where you want the ListFragment placed, and afterwards use getChildFragmentManager() to get a FragmentManager, that you can place the ListFragment with.

Comment: Within the FrameLayout XML, should I have a ListView or TextView?

Comment: It should just be an empty framelayout with an ID that you use as the container

Comment: Unfortunately that just places the listfragment on top of my current fragment.

Comment: Are you adding two fragments to the same FrameLayout?

Comment: So, I can get it to show by scrapping the added ListFragment and just using a ListView in the parent fragment. However, this listview won't scroll along with the screen.

Comment: just add the fragment to an additional FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
private void showComments(JSONArray comments) {
        ListFragment newFragment = CommentsFragment.newInstance(comments);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: What's the use of the `R.id.content` tag? I already inflated the CommentsFragment with `R.layout.comments_list'.

Comment: @MilesPeele R.id.content is the root layout which holds the view.. so use R.layout.comments_lis instead R.id.content.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. I'm getting a "no view found for id" exception when I do that though.

Comment: @MilesPeele post your main layout.

Comment: well it works now, thanks. I had to use a completely different method to get the fragment to show. Now I just need to figure out how to embed the dialog fragment within its parent fragment instead of displaying as a floating window... any ideas?